# Почему не работает вызов метода по таймеру каждые 5 секунд?

Tags: c#

на сайте есть кнопки, на которые браузер постоянно жмёт, каждые 5 секунд страница догружается и появляются новые кнопки с одним и тем же именем, вопрос - как заставить таймер каждые 5 секунд вызывать метод, жмущий на кнопку? Вот как делаю:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
            myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"); //исключение тут
            foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
            {
                if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "button-text follow-text")
                {
                    elmBtn.Focus();
                    elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
```

но выбивает исключение: `System.InvalidCastException`. без таймера кнопки жмутся прекрасно, код клика верный

Comment: Есть подозрение что страница не успевает загрузиться, либо метод вызываемый таймером обращается не к той странице.

Comment: ну, я жду пока страница полностью прогрузится и только потом жму на кнопку, которая должна вызывать метод

Comment: Дайте stacktrace исключения. Какой объект приводится к какому типу?

Comment: А почему у вас таймер System.Timers.Timer myTimer объявлен как локальная переменная?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать все-таки [таймер из библиотеки WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) - чтобы не ловить проблем с многопоточностью.

Answer (score 2):

Советую использовать вот таймер из пространства Threading.

```
 System.Threading.Timer service = new System.Threading.Timer(Update, null, 0, 5000);
    .....
       private void Update(object obj)
        {
         .....
        }
```

Comment: В таком случае появятся еще и проблемы с потоками...

Answer (score -1):

```
        void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Action action = () =>
            {
                HtmlElementCollection elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"); //исключение тут
                foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
                {
                    if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "button-text follow-text")
                    {
                        elmBtn.Focus();
                        elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    }
                }
            };

            webBrowser1.Invoke(action);
        }
```